# custom function not working with post data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a simple password hashing function:

```
function create_hash($password)
{
    $salt = 'HN|fQyjB.{G~tB%)GxpQ6)1;fW|dr9}ME)np|4@%D]ciL|xI~FqXnvoJs.-.30q}';
    $salt2 = '1e,/]$rc4 +`e==H(^bV+ZBh!p<';
    $hashed_password = md5(strval($salt.$password.$salt2));
    return $hashed_password;
}
```

But when I call my function to hash the password , I get an error.

```
  $data = array(
 'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
 'password'=> create_hash($this->input->post('password')),
  );
```

When I replace my create_hash with Codeigniter's md5, everything works fine. Maybe I am doing something wrong, and someone could give me suggestions. How can I do custom hashing properly

Comment: My project is on ipage hosting , 
error is : Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://sludinajumi.mikasenoks.com/login/signup_validation. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. But as i said, with just md5 , everything is working fine.

Comment: Where is create_hash() defined? A helper? Within the controller/class calling it?

Comment: i defined create_hash() in my Model. And im calling it in same Model few lines below.

Comment: Use should be using $this->create_hash() then.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happen, because of the scope, where your try to call function 'create_hash', and this function out of the scope. if you define the function in the class, just use $this->create_hash(); if not help,  You can check php log or apache log for more error detail.